# Move ball inside another big ball and collide with walls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, collision-detection, trigonometry, angle

The ball must move and when it touches the walls of the bigger circle, it should change self.x and self.y.

I have a function that generates an array of new Ball(config). Inside each Ball I have a self.move function

The problem is that I don't know how to modify x and y. This is my code.

https://github.com/oanapopescu93/casino/blob/master/client/src/components/pages/games/keno.js

Comment: to modify `x` you can "add" a number to it, or "subtract" a number from it ... e.g. `x = x + 10` ... you've modified `x`

Comment: I've already done that. self.x = self.x + self.dir_x and self.y = self.y + self.dir_y. The problem is how to change self.dir_x and self.dir_y after the collision